ASP.NET Core Service Worker and Web API
Can you help me to figure it out?
I have an ASP.NET Core Web API with identity server and Entity Framework, in a single solution with worker service. I saw that in ASP.NET MVC people connect them as separate "apps", but I can't figure it out how to connect them in such way in solution.
I can connect service worker in Web API startup, but in such way it just start. But I can't connect it in service worker with possibility to get data from the DbContext.
I tried to connect them via services.AddScoped (I created additional service) but it worked only from Web API. And service worker just get an error.

Not sure how anyone can help you if you don't give example code or error messages. Additionally, I don't actually understand what you mean by "separate apps"

What you have done and what's the error you get? With .NET, you can use the BackgroundService, which is an implementation of IHostedService, or implement your own. Reference:Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core which inject the service by services.AddHostedService<XXX>();
